# Angular5 input with date

Tags: html, date, datepicker, angular5

I defined an input with type date in angular5, in this way:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="activity.subActivitiesList[4].releaseDate" type='date'/>
```

and when I pick a date from the webpage and insert it into db all works fine. But when I read the date from db and show it in the previous field the date (in timestamp) doesn't appear. Can you tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the problem. First of all thanks for your replies, the right solution was precisely the use of the pipe BUT:
1) the date format of the pipe MUST be the same as the date is retrieved;
2) the date format of the pipe MUST NOT be the same as the user will see it.

For example: in my case the db date format was 'yyyy-MM-dd' but the shown date format was 'dd/MM/yyyy'. So the pipe had to be be set with 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Answer (score 0):

Add the format of date should be displayed using piping. Format could be like short Date, etc

Comment: I added the pipe in this way but nothing changes: <input [ngModel]="activity.subActivitiesList[4].releaseDate | date:'dd/MM/yy'" type='date' (ngModelChange)="activity.subActivitiesList[4].releaseDate=$event" />

Comment: Please have a look at this angular date filters. Use  "M/d/yy" For month/date/year. https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp . And for displaying on UI use interpolation like this {{..display date here..}}

Answer (score 0):

```
This can be done using pipes,

Template:
 <input [value]="birthDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' " type='date' />
 <button (click)="setBirthDate()">Set Date</button>

Typescript:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  birthDate = '';

  setBirthDate(){
    this.birthDate = '05/05/1990';
  }
}


**[Live Demo:][1]**


  [1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxvlzv
```

Comment: if i insert the type='date' it doesn't work, but if i remove the type, it works fine. Does the type create confusion?

Answer (score 0):

The date can be converted to 'yyyy-MM-dd' from typescript.check the below code.

// HTML

```
     <input [(ngModel)]="date" name="date" type='text' />
     <button (click)="setDate()">Set Date</button>
```

//Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'

@Component({
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 })

 export class TestComponent {

     constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){}

     date : any;

     setDate(){     

         this.date = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

     }

 }
```

and add 'DatePipe' in app.module.ts

import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@ngModules ({

...
    providers: [DatePipe]

})

Comment: it's a rest response so the pipe would be the best solution if it worked